# Avoid race condition using RDBMS transaction

Tags: microservices, message-queue, distributed-computing, distributed-system

I am working on design of a distributed system which will process some events. For simplicity lets say, multiple instance of same service will be consuming from same queue, every message will have a id and it will read the current value of it from the DB and increment it by 1 and update in DB.
The service has a SQL with transaction;
Sudo code:

```
.
.
.
start transaction
   count <- read the value from db for the said id
   if no record found
       count <- 0
   count <- count + 1
   update the DB for the said id
commit
.
.
.
```

Consider, current DB state at 9:59:00:00 am

```
--------
id | val
--------
0  | 4
--------
```

There are 2 instances of the service are available and there is one event with id = 1 at 9:59:20:00 am;
If the Service(instance-1) takes 3 second to make the updation in DB then at 9:59:23:00 am DB state will be

```
--------
id | val
--------
0  | 4
1  | 1
--------
```

Now there are two events with id = 2 at the same time or very close interval. Say,

```
Event-1 at 10:00:00:00 am  
Event-2 at 10:00:00:50 am
```

Service instance-1 takes 3 second to process Event-1 and Service instance-2 takes 2 second to process Event-2.

Will this produce any inconsistency, or very time in such scenario it will produce same result (At 10:00:06:00 am for id=2, value=2)

To handle this kind of race condition any other good design pattern available, like locking

Thanks in advance for considering this problem statement

Comment: I think this question is off-topic at this site and probably better suited at the software engineering site.

Comment: Hi @JeffHolt, thanks for informing me, I was not aware of this. Let me ask it there as well. Thank you

Comment: @JeffHolt There isn't any code here to review, it is all design.

Comment: @pacmaninbw This site is for fixing code problems. The lack of code makes it off-topic. Where it *should* be posted is up for debate (on meta not here).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a record in the table: [id=1&count=2]

Typical approach for updates is:

> update count = count + 1 where id = 1

In most databases this update is considered "atomic" - two threads running at the same time will still update the row twice.

In case you do need the code to retry, the update would look like:

> update count = count + 1 where id = 1 and count = 2

This would allow the caller to see if their update was applied or not; and retry if needed.

As for insert, this is trickier:

- option one is to have some kind of lock somewhere (as you can't put a lock on a row which does not exist) - predicate, table, etc.
- another option, and I would go with this one, if a row does not exist, issue an INSERT statement. If two threads try to insert at the same time, only one will succeed, the other one will have to retry with an update